MB-Lab setup help
I am new to both blender and MB-Lab, I have installed MB-Lab as an add on to blender but cannot figure out for the life of me how to use it in blender.  The add ons section shows that I have it installed and a check next to it shows that it should be working, but I can't seem to figure out how to import a human model into blender from MB-Lab.  ChatGPT says it will be in the toolbar section by view, but it is not showing up on my computer.
Does anyone know how to fix this?  It woul dbe a huge help!

Hi. According to this page: https://blender-addons.org/mb-lab-add-on/ it is a character creation tool. It doesn't say anything about importing a model. I took a very quick look at the addon and didn't see any import option, but I could have missed something.

As @curious_1 said, it is for character creation. It is used to create characters directly in Blender, not necessarily to import them from somewhere else. But there is a "File Tools" section which has an "Import character" button. But ChatGPT is wrong, the toolbar is what you bring up with the T shortcut on the left side of the viewport, but it is on the right side panel , shortcut N, there it has an extra tab - most likely at the very bottom when it is installed at last.
